# Is current the same coming out of an IC as it was going in?

Tags: current, resistors, integrated-circuit

[image: diagram]
<sub>(source: [fatcow.com](http://johnnystarrnet.fatcow.com/images/AND.png))</sub>

This is my first diagram so keep that in mind.  I've come up with this circuit because
I've got some 74** series ICs and I want to be able to make them work.  This example is
a simple AND gate with the 7409 IC.

Obviously, if the circuit works, the LED should glow but only if both switches are on.
What I don't know is what the current will be when it gets to the LED.

The reason I'm not sure is what happens to the current when it is output from pin 3?

R1, and R2 slow down the current so that it can safely enter pins 1 and 2.  But is the
470 ohm resistor required to protect the LED?

Comment: What color is the LED?

Comment: The LED is red.  Is that a joke?

Comment: No, it's not, all LEDs have different forward voltages and current requirements, but there are some generalizations that can be made about each color.

Comment: Hahaha "Is that a joke?" Not making fun of anybody, but that was really entertaining to me.

Answer (score 12):

The 7409 is a Quad packed 2 input AND Gate with **Open Collector Outputs**. It needs a pull up on the output pin 3 to work. And it can only sink 16mA when the output is logic level low. Logic level high leaves the internal open collector transistor off, with a leak current of 250µA, only if the external pullup is there. **It won't work at all in the setup you have pictured.**

[image: Schematic]

Notice the Output Y is connected to a transistor's Collector. Current would flow from external vcc through (in your case) the resistor and led, into the collector and out through ground (Or other way around depending on your school of thought). But you would need to connect the led/resistor to VCC, not Ground. And mind the 16mA limit. (Which is listed for TI's SN7409, not sure about the original 7409's maximum current)

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple mistakes in this circuit:

1. The switches won't work as expected, because you need a pull-down resistor to force the inputs low when the switches are open;
2. The current coming out of the AND gate won't be dependent on the current on its inputs (virtually zero). In fact, it will be directly taken from the supply pins.

Anyway, directly answering the question in the title, **yes** the current going out of any component is the same of the current going in. But, in this case, it will enter from the supply and exit either from the ground or from the output. In any case, for the Kirchoff's law of current, in every component (or block, or node) the sum of entering currents must be equal to the sum of exiting currents.

Comment: The pictured gate is an AND. If it were a NAND, it would have been more obvious that the current has to come from the supply pins, since a NAND can have a high output with both inputs low.

Comment: @Random832 thank you for pointing that :)

Answer (score 3):

Pin 3 delivers a voltage at its output, depending on whether it is a 0 or a 1 it will be (approximately) 0V or 5V. Note that you mention 6V, which is not a good idea for a 74xx chip. 74HCxx chips are more tolerant.

The current required to provide those voltage come from the ground and power pins, not from the inputs.

If you chip is really a 74xx (old style TTL) it will regard floating (unconnected) inputs as 1 (high). Short the input to ground (no resistor necessary) to make it a 0.

Answer (score 3):

The current through the LED won't depend on R1 and R2.

When both inputs are high, the output is latched up to the supply rail. Current will flow through pin 14, through the resistor, then the LED.
Because of this you can assume the output as a voltage and calculate the current from there: (Vsupply - Diode formward voltage drop)/R3  (approximate because diode forward voltage drop changes with current).

Also I don't think the circuit will work well because your switches only ever pull each input high. When they're not on, the inputs will be floating and will behave strangely.
You should have the resistors R1 and R2 attached from the inputs to ground, then the switches from the inputs to the 6V.

Cheers